# Getting 'top: Unknown terminal "dumb" in $TERM' in Linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm getting this error whenever executing the `top` command in Linux remotely via SSH:

```
top: Unknown terminal "dumb" in $TERM
```

My Java application which monitors the performance of the remote machine uses the output of top command.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Similar questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194022/20626 and https://serverfault.com/q/304470/121920

Answer (score 3):

Try passing the **-b** option to top. From the manual:

```
b Batch mode. Useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file. In this mode, top will 
  not accept command line input. It runs until it produces the number of iterations requested with the n 
  option or until killed. Output is plain text suitable for display on a dumb terminal.
```

Comment: I got the above mentioned message while using the ```-b``` option on Slackware. Top seems to be looking for dumb terminal definition when output is send to a file.

Answer (score 1):

top probably could not find "dumb" terminal definition neither in file `$HOME/.terminfo/d/dumb` nor `/usr/share/terminfo/d/dumb` at the remote machine.

Maybe that file is placed in other location - just copy it or make a symlink. 
If it does not exist at all then get that file from some other linux system and place it in one of the above mentioned locations